# Vue Cli 3.0 where is the config file?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I've seen it mentioned in docs, etc the vue.config.js file.
And also noted previously these are handled in the webpack config file, etc in 2.0.
But I can't find either file in my project folder created with vue cli 3.0... Where is the config files and why isn't it anywhere in the top level folders, etc?

Comment: What command did you use to create the vue cli project?  For using webpack you need to use something like `vue init webpack your-project`

Comment: @skribe I've used vue create my-project as the old way of selecting webpack or others are no longer used in 3.0

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> Where is the config files and why isn't it anywhere in the top level folders, etc?

The initial project doesn't require the file to exist because you just created a project with fresh "default" settings that don't require any config.

Just create it yourself. it's even mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/README.md#configuration):

> Many aspects of a Vue CLI project can be configured **by placing** a vue.config.js file at the root of your project. The file **may** already exist depending on the features you selected when creating the project.

(*emphasis mine*)

Edit: now to be found here: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config

Comment: Ah, got it! So sorry, I kept reading all those configurations and options but I missed the word 'placing' your own config file... =(

Comment: It may be documented in the README, but we're finding the answer here likely via google despite the 190+ unrelated search hits at github's vuejs/vue-cli repo. Nonetheless, thanks for pointing out the details.

Comment: For the record, it's not documented in the README anymore, as of today.

Comment: Correct, it can now be found in the new documentation we put online when we left beta: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config

Answer (score 18):

The file by default does **not** exists as it was mentioned by Linus. You need to create manually `vue.config.js` file in a root location of your project, i.e. on the same level where is `package.json`.

Comment: Makes it a lot more clear when you say 'same level where package.json', this is good simple answer, should be top rated.

Answer (score 10):

There is no need for "config" directory anymore.
if you want to define "environment variables" you can do that in ".env" file

Just like:

```
VUE_APP_TITLE=Test
```

You can also create ".env" file for each environment

Like:

`.env.development` for development mode

`.env.production` for production mode.

For more information please read:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode

Comment: The current Vue CLI docs specifically tell you to make changes to the `vue.config.js` config...

Comment: One extremely annoying thing about .env files is that they don't properly support JSON configurations but you have to use JSON.parse().

Answer (score 6):

`vue.config.js` is now an optional config file.

Refer: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

1. Create

> vue.config.js

in your vue project at the same level with

> package.json

2. Specify the host and the port:`module.exports = { devServer: { host: "localhost", port: "8080" } }`
3. Run:

> npm run serve

in your vue folder.

Check out this screenshot:
[Hope it helps!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B8mg.png)

PS: If you want to disable running the app on a local host check out this post: [How do I disable running an app on the local network when using vue-cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829363/how-do-i-disable-running-an-app-on-the-local-network-when-using-vue-cli)