# How do I disable running an app on the local network when using vue-cli?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

When I run a vue-cli project I see this:

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 5778ms

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.178.9:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

I don’t want my app to be running on the local network, only local host.
How do I turn the local network part off?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
// vue.config.js
{
  devServer: {
    host: "localhost"
  }
}
```

Setting `host` to `"localhost"` will disable network access in the webpack-dev-server.

```
App running at:
 - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
 - Network: unavailable
```

Comment: However, when I do not even have this config file in my project, in one machine it works well but in another machine it reports network unavailable.

Comment: @K.Symbol seems like your problem is vice-versa. It seems like you would like be able to access the application on the network but the question was about blocking the ability to access the application on the network :)

Comment: I have this problem with network unavailable and I want to fix it. How can I do it? I don't have the config.js file