# entrypoint size limit: code splitting to limit the size of entrypoints in vue cli 3.x

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I get the following `warning` after building my project with vue cli 3:

[image]

After some look up I found out that there is no need to create a `webpack.config.js` as it is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423756/vue-cli-3-0-where-is-the-config-file) (or [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/where-to-configure-vue-cli3-webpack-base-conf-js/43803)):

> The initial project doesn't require the file to exist because you just created a project with fresh "default" settings that don't require any config.

The [Vue CLI documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) offers a `vue.config.js` which is optional and will be automatically loaded if it's present in the project root. Also it seems possible to work with webpack in the `vue.config.js` like [this](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html).

I'm totally new to webpack and couldn't figure out how to limit the size of my entrypoints with the code splitting that is provided in the message of the `warning` abouve. Can somebody please give me a hint how to solve this using the `vue.config.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your components [asynchronously](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components).

Also prefer local component registration over global.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I did the following in my `app.vue`: `'mk-footer': () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "navFooter" */ './components/Footer.vue') ...` and it reduced my entrypoint down to 274Kib. Is there anything else to further improve the entrypoint size? I've tried lazy loading the routes, but that didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

We can also split each route's component into separate chunks and only load them when the route is visited.

In your `router.js` file:

```
// replace
// import UserDetails from './views/UserDetails'
// with
const UserDetails = () => import('./views/UserDetails')

const router = createRouter({
  // ...
  routes: [{ path: '/users/:id', component: UserDetails }],
})
```

For further information read the official [documentation](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BWappsandmore. Unfortunately I stopped working with Vue 1 1/2 years ago and can't try out your answer.